# Extension of domain of contactive semigroups, and why contractivity is important?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

I am reading a paper, where I think the authors use this fact that the contractivity of a semigroup on a space of initial values, imeadiatly implies that we can extend the domain of semigroup to this space. Do you think that am I right?

Also, I have another question that, why contactivity of semigroup is important. Why if we have
$$ \| S(t) \| \leq 2 $$ 
the semigroup $S(t)$ does not enjoy the properties of the contractive semigroups?

Comment: I am not too familiar with semigroups but here what I think about your last question: I would think that contractivity is not the important part but boundedness.
If I remember correctly It can be shown that for a bounded $C_0$-semigroup that it is possible to find an equivalent norm on the Banach/Hilbertspace such that the semigroup is contractive.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\|S(t)\|\le M$ for some constant and $\lim_{t\downarrow 0}S(t)x=x$ for all $x$. Then you can renorm by defining $\|x\|_S=\sup_{t \ge 0}\|S(t)x\|$. The two norms are equivalent because
$$
           \|x\| \le \|x\|_S \le M\|x\|.
$$
$S$ becomes a contractive semigroup in the new norm:
$$
      \|S(t)x\|_{S} = \sup_{t' \ge 0 }\|S(t')S(t)x\|=\sup_{t' \ge 0}\|S(t'+t)x\| \le \|x\|_S.
$$

Comment: So what are contractive semigroups important for?